# How to implement an efficient im2col function in C++ using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I've been trying to implement `im2col` function present in MATLAB and GNU Octave. I found it hard to understand the implementation present in Octave's source code, so I ran the function on few matrices to understand the logic behind it. Using that, I've implemented the same in C++ using OpenCV, and although the result seems to be the same, it's awfully slow.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Mat input = Mat::eye(100,100,CV_32FC1);
    input.at<float>(1,2) = 2;   //Makes it easier to verify the correct solution
    int rowBlock = 7;
    int colBlock = 5;

    int m = input.rows;
    int n = input.cols;

    int x = m - rowBlock + 1;
    int y = n - colBlock + 1;

    Mat result = Mat::zeros(1,rowBlock*colBlock,CV_32FC1);

    for(int i = 0; i< y; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< x; j++)
        {
            Mat temp2 = input.rowRange(j,j+rowBlock).colRange(i,i+colBlock).t();
            temp2 = temp2.reshape(1,1);
            vconcat(result,temp2,result);
        }
    }
    result = result.rowRange(1,result.rows);
    cout << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to improve on it? I'm sure I might be doing a lot of things very inefficiently here.

Comment: dont know what im2col should do, but I guess it's result would be a 9024 x 35 matrix in your example? Are the elements in each block just written to a row in the result? If yes, what's the ordering? First row of the block in the first elements of the row in the result? second row of the block just after that?

Comment: you have a problem with rows and cols mixed unintuitively with x and y. Maybe your problem is, that your outer loop is over columns and your inner loop is over rows, which is against the data ordering, leading to caching problems.

Comment: @Micka - `im2col` is a MATLAB function that takes every possible pixel neighbourhood of a known size, converts them into stacked 1D columns, and a matrix is created that concatenates all of these columns together.  I use it all the time when I want to implement a filter that doesn't have a built-in equivalent in MATLAB.

Comment: is the ordering of the stacked neighborhood important? I would have assumed col-first ordering, but your code gives row-first ordering. Those things are important if you want most efficiency. However, my posted answer should give the same results as your posting, but should be much faster.

Comment: @Micka - It isn't my code or my post, but yes it does it in a col-first ordering.  It grabs pixel neighbourhoods column wise, and orders the pixel neighbourhood such that the columns get unrolled first.  As such, if we had a pixel neighbourhood that was `{{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};`, it would become such that: `{1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9};`.

Comment: Does my posted answer not work as you want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is much faster for me:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::Mat::eye(100,100,CV_32FC1);
    input.at<float>(1,2) = 2;   //Makes it easier to verify the correct solution
    int rowBlock = 7;
    int colBlock = 5;

    int m = input.rows;
    int n = input.cols;

    // using right x = col; y = row
    int yB = m - rowBlock + 1;
    int xB = n - colBlock + 1;

    // you know the size of the result in the beginning, so allocate it all at once
    cv::Mat result2 = cv::Mat::zeros(xB*yB,rowBlock*colBlock,CV_32FC1);
    for(int i = 0; i< yB; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< xB; j++)
        {
            // here yours is in different order than I first thought:
            //int rowIdx = j + i*xB;    // my intuition how to index the result
            int rowIdx = i + j*yB;

            for(unsigned int yy =0; yy < rowBlock; ++yy)
                for(unsigned int xx=0; xx < colBlock; ++xx)
                {
                    // here take care of the transpose in the original method
                    //int colIdx = xx + yy*colBlock; // this would be not transposed
                    int colIdx = xx*rowBlock + yy; 

                    result2.at<float>(rowIdx,colIdx) = input.at<float>(i+yy, j+xx);
                }

        }
    }
    // check your output here...
}
```

I added it to your code, to test the equality (it would be better to write a function for each one and encapsulate, though ;) )

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::Mat::eye(100,100,CV_32FC1);
    input.at<float>(1,2) = 2;   //Makes it easier to verify the correct solution
    int rowBlock = 7;
    int colBlock = 5;

    int m = input.rows;
    int n = input.cols;

    // here, your naming of x and y is counter intuitive for me, since I see x being linked to cols normally (e.g. direction of x-axis)
    int x = m - rowBlock + 1;
    int y = n - colBlock + 1;

    cv::Mat result = cv::Mat::zeros(1,rowBlock*colBlock,CV_32FC1);

    for(int i = 0; i< y; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< x; j++)
        {
            cv::Mat temp2 = input.rowRange(j,j+rowBlock).colRange(i,i+colBlock).t();
            temp2 = temp2.reshape(1,1);
            cv::vconcat(result,temp2,result);
        }
    }
    result = result.rowRange(1,result.rows);

    std::cout << result.rows << " x " << result.cols << std::endl;

    char w;
    std::cin >> w;


    // using right x = col; y = row
    int yB = m - rowBlock + 1;
    int xB = n - colBlock + 1;

    // you know the size of the result in the beginning, so allocate it all at once
    cv::Mat result2 = cv::Mat::zeros(x*y,rowBlock*colBlock,CV_32FC1);
    for(int i = 0; i< yB; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< xB; j++)
        {
            // here yours is in different order than I first thought:
            //int rowIdx = j + i*xB;    // my intuition how to index the result
            int rowIdx = i + j*yB;

            for(unsigned int yy =0; yy < rowBlock; ++yy)
                for(unsigned int xx=0; xx < colBlock; ++xx)
                {
                    // here take care of the transpose in the original method
                    //int colIdx = xx + yy*colBlock; // this would be not transposed
                    int colIdx = xx*rowBlock + yy; 

                    result2.at<float>(rowIdx,colIdx) = input.at<float>(i+yy, j+xx);
                }

        }
    }



    std::cout << result2.rows << " x " << result2.cols << std::endl;
    std::cin >> w;

    // test whether both results are the same:
    bool allGood = true;
    for(int j=0; j<result.rows; ++j)
        for(int i=0; i<result.cols; ++i)
        {
            if(result.at<float>(j,i) != result2.at<float>(j,i))
            {
                    std::cout << "("<<j<<","<<i<<") = " << result.at<float>(j,i) << " != " << result2.at<float>(j,i) << std::endl;
                    allGood = false;
            }
        }
    if(allGood) std::cout << "matrices are equal" << std::endl;

    std::cin >> w;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is excellent! I only had to transpose the resultant matrix for my application, but thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: Nice to hear! The code might be even more efficient if you consider the transposing already during/before computation, but if it is fast enough I guess it is not worth the work :)